# Can't access K8S cluster IP of Kind cluster running on macOS

Tags: mac-osx, kubernetes

I have created a K8S cluster on a macOS machine using `kind`. I have an `echo-service` running on that cluster that I can access on localhost when `kubectl port-forward  svc/echo-service 7893:7893` is running.

I would have expected to be able to access the service on the K8S cluster IP (`http://10.104.60.162:7893/`), but that doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Relating the default **kind** configuration, the cluster is configured to be reachable only on localhost.
To allow the network access through all the ip addresses of the server, you have to configure the port listing on **0.0.0.0**, this means that your cluster will be reachable at both **localhost & 10.104.60.162**.

Create a yaml config file as shown

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
networking:
  apiServerAddress: 0.0.0.0
  apiServerPort: 7893
```

After saving the config to `kind-custom-config.yaml`, you create your cluster :

```
kind create cluster --config kind-custom-config.yaml
```

Checkout through `kubectl cluster-info` than you are good to go

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://0.0.0.0:7893
KubeDNS is running at https://0.0.0.0:7893/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try and run `curl localhost:7893` instead.
Please take a look also at [docker for Mac issues](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2445)